# Cannot drop database because it is currently in use MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I'm brand new to using MVC, and I'm trying to use an initializer to initialize data into my DB when the application is first started.  Here is what I've got in Global.asax.cs:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyAppInitializer());
 MyAppContext db = new MyAppContext();
 db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

In Web.config, here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyAppContext"
  connectionString="data source= MyServer; Integrated Security=True; database=MyDatabase"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is using MS SQL 2008 R2.  My Initializer looks like this:

```
public class MyAppInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyAppContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyAppContext context)
    {
        var organizations = new List<Organizations>
        {
            new Organizations { OrgName = "AT", OrgPhone = 5093333433, OrgOfficeLocation = "ITB", OrgPointOfContact = "Tony", OrgIsActive = 1 },
            new Organizations { OrgName = "Libraries", OrgPhone = 5093331122, OrgOfficeLocation = "Holland-Terrell", OrgPointOfContact = "Herald", OrgIsActive = 1 }
        };
        organizations.ForEach(s => context.Organizations.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I made sure I closed my connection to the server and database in SQL Server Management Studio, but multiple people have access to this DB, although none should be using it right now.  How can I get it so I can initialize this data in my DB?  Thanks!

Edit: I've already got the DB created on the server, but it is completely empty (no tables, procedures, etc).  Would this cause an issue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In SSMS run something like this...

```
USE master -- be sure that you're not on MYDB
ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DROP DATABASE MYDB;
```

Comment: I get a syntax error: incorrect syntax near 'IMMEDIATE'  I took that out and ran it, but it just ran for about 5 minutes before I stopped it, in which case I got this error: The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: Works for ***LocalDB*** using _mdf file_ ? using `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True`

Answer (score 50):

I faced a similar issue today when using MVC codefirst. After 20 mins of trying out various stuff I noticed that, the "Server Explorer" tab in Visual Studio had a connection open to my database. After I "closed" the connection in the server explorer tab of visual studio, the code was able to run and automatically recreate the database.

Comment: Funny, Visual Studio (using VS 2015) open connection and can't handle this case by itself !

Comment: @TwoPea I had the same problem with LocalDb that is being used in a sample MVC project. Your solution resolved it.

Comment: This is the actual solution and should be the accepted as answer,

Answer (score 8):

[image: VS2015 close DB connection]
As described by Vardhini... close DB connection in Server Explorer.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` applies to ***LocalDB*** ?

Answer (score 4):

In the SSMS "Delete" window make sure that "Close existing connections" is checked.

Comment: After trying all these ways to get the db to drop, I closed SSMS, closed the data connections in VS, and then closed VS. Opened VS, checked to make sure connections were still shut, ran the application. That worked.

Comment: This worked. Check "Close existing connections" and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Closing all existing  connections of the database in visual studio server explorer and SQLManagement studio solved the problem for me.

Comment: can I do it ***programmatically*** _in visual studio server explorer_ ?

Comment: Yeah I tried a lot of things as well but found out that I had an open query results window open in SQL Mgmt Studio and my .NET app wouldn't work until I closed that and restarted the SQL services on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

My observations are:

1. Cannot be logged in to application
2. Cannot be connected to db with Server Explorer
3. Cannot be connected with SSMS

Then the application rebuild DB even when `Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new DbInitializer());` is in `public DbContext();` - NOT as other answears stand to put it into `Application_Start();`

Comment: After trying all these ways to get the db to drop, I closed SSMS, closed the data connections in VS, and then closed VS. Opened VS, checked to make sure connections were still shut, ran the application. That worked.